# Jenkins hangs when using Chrome but is OK with Firefox

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium-cucumber project that runs just fine at the command line with `"mvn clean intall" or "mvn test"`.

It runs fine with Firefox and Chrome on my machine.

BUT, when I installed Jenkins locally on my machine, and run my project with Chrome, it hangs through Jenkins. With Firefox it runs just fine.

From the Jenkins console I am receiving the following error:

```
Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
```

I don't understand why Chrome is running ok using my IntelliJ and/or command line, but with Jenkins locally on my machine, Chrome becomes a problem.

I'm running Chrome 66.0.3359.181
Selenium 3.12
maven-compiler-plugin 3.7

Comment: Ok I think I fixed my issue, I did so by running head-less. Only problem with that is I think screenshots does not work in headless, as I had an error and no screenshot was taken in my report